# Permutation test to overcome autocorrelation issues?

Tags: regression, permutation-test

let's say, I want to track a rowing team's (collective) performance on some task and show that it increases with practice. I have a metric, i.e. the time to measure their performance.
Now I would like to show if/that the team's practice increases (and that possibility that the increase is caused by chance is smaller than a given alpha), i.e. that there is a negative slope in the metric. I could compute a regression, however, I know that my data-points are not independent, as I keep measuring the same team.
Ergo, if I compute the p-values from the correlation coefficient, I can't rely on that (correct me, if I'm wrong).

Simply subtracting the t+1-data is not an option, as my assumption is that between every measurement, substantial increases in performance occur due to practice. So in this way, I can't disentangle e.g. autocorrelation in the data and a real "trend".

Is a permutation test a way to obtain a more realistic estimate?

The logic is the following: If I compute e.g. R2 for randomly assigned timestamps and compare it to the actual R2 of my performance data, I should obtain a probability distribution which will (for sufficiently many tests) also include the data in which the actual trend is removed, but the autocorrelations are captured and compare the R2 against this distribution of R2s.
So is the empirical p-value a more realistic estimate of my hypothetical rowing team's performance?

Thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: Your language is too vague for us readers to be sure about what you're doing, but I wonder about the concern over independence.  If you are performing least squares regression, what matters is that the *responses* be *conditionally uncorrelated,* not that everything be independent. For other forms of regression, *conditional* independence is the requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! 
What (exactly) do you mean by conditionally uncorrelated? Does it mean that my measurements only have to be "independent" in the sense that e.g. the training-effect I would like to measure is always measured under the same condition and e.g. with enough time between time points such that e.g. the fatigue after measuring at time t does not spill over into measurement at time t+1?

Also, could you maybe give a hint how to make my language more precise?

Comment: In regression, everything is conditional on the explanatory variables, which themselves may be strongly interdependent and correlated.  It always helps to express your model formally using mathematical and probabilistic notation: that clearly shows what the random variables are and helps you determine whether the model is applicable.

Comment: Thank you, @whuber! 
Formally, my predictor would be something like N practice sessions, and the criterion would be the race time. So practice will cumulate in the team, as this is the point. Is it then permissible to compute a regression and can I take the corresponding p-value at face value? I.e. if race times do decrease as a result of practice within the same team?